# Influxdb Versioning / Audit Data

Tags: java, influxdb

Suppose simple measurement 'price':

```
time (time_of_message):1500180569257
message_tag_key:trade
price_field_key:99
```

Suppose we want to version this data so that at some point in future if there is an update or correction but we want to retain the original record, what is the best way to do this?

My current approach is to add a message insert time tag so that versions/corrections can be indexed vs using a message_insert_field:

```
time (time_of_message):1500180569257
message_tag_key:trade
message_insert_time_tag_key:1500180569368
price_field_key:99
```

is there a better way, especially if no of corrections small?